# A nice identity involving urns and balls problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, generating-functions

Prove the identity: $$\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{a} {n+a-k-2\choose n-2}}{\displaystyle {n+a-1\choose a}} = 1$$ where $C_{i}^{j}$ is defined as the number of ways to simultaneously choose $j$ objects from $i$ objects.

**My attempt:** I was trying to use a combinatorial argument by saying that out of the given $n$ balls, each of the terms within the summation is the probability of a given urn containing exactly $k$ balls for $k = 0,1,2,...,n$. Thus, the sum reflects the sum of all the probabilities of that urn having exactly $k$ balls, so it must be $1$.

**My question:** I would like to see an algebraic proof for this identity. Could someone please help with such a proof? In case my argument above is incorrect, please help point out the mistake.

Comment: Fixed it! Please give it a thought if you could.

Comment: What is meant by "simultaneously choose"? If you mean that $C_i^j$ is the number of $i$- element subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,j\}$, one standard notation is ${j \choose i}$.

Comment: @Aravind yes, that's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a variation based upon the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
  [x^k](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{k}
  \end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+a-k-2}{n-2}&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{-n+1}{a-k}(-1)^{a-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty[x^{a-k}](1+x)^{-n+1}(-1)^{a-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^a[x^a](1+x)^{-n+1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-x)^k\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^a[x^a](1+x)^{-n}\tag{4}\\
> &=(-1)^a\binom{-n}{a}\tag{5}\\
> &=\binom{n+a-1}{a}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q$ with $p=n-1$ and $q=a-k$.
- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule
  $$[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$$ We also extend the upper range of the series to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (4) we use the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $x^a$.
- In (6) we use again the binomial identity as we did in (1).

Comment: Thank you very much. Great solution. Could you give this problem a try as well? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912452/prove-that-a-given-probability-forms-a-probability-measure-with-binomial-distrib

Comment: @user177196: You're welcome! I've added an answer to your referred question. Regards,

Comment: Did you make a typo in the identity used in $(1)$? I could not see how you ended up with $-n+1\choose a-k$ as $q = n-2$ and $p= 2-n-a+k$

Comment: @user177196: I've added the settings in the comment section. Note that $(-1)^q=(-1)^{-q}$. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

${n+a-1 \choose n-1}={n+a-1 \choose a}$ is the number of non-negative integer solutions to:

$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=a$

Let $x_1=k$ with $k \in \{0,1,\ldots,a\}$. Then the corresponding number of solutions is ${n+a-k-2 \choose n-2}$.

Comment: this is the combinatorial approach, which I mentioned above. Thank you for posting though